# How do I get 'puts' messages and standard output sent to a file while using RSpec / parallel_rspec?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

This is the contents of my .rspec_parallel file.  I am using parallel_tests gem to run tests in multiple browser instances.  To my knowledge, the gem uses the same formatter options available in RSpec.

```
--format html --out results<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>.html
```

This works fantastic and I'm able to get the HTML output I normally see from RSpec.  However, all of the 'puts' messages and basic standard output is logged to my console window, and not to the HTML files.

How can I get this output into each individual HTML file that I have set up?

Answer (score 0):

`puts` will output to `$stdout` where as `output` is actually an instance variable of the `RSpec::Core::Formatters::BaseFormatter` class. `output` is defaulted to `$stdout` but when you pass in a string it determines that it should create a new `StringIO` and then output this to the given file name. Thus `puts` will not append to the `@output` variable.

You could do something ugly like create a runner file like

```
File.open('some_file_name.html','w+') do |file|
  file << `rspec spec --format html` 
end
```

Then this file will have the output from `$stdout`but your `puts` code will not be html formatted in this case. Other than that you could try building your own [Custom Formatter](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters) but it will probably take quite a bit of source searching to make sure you can capture everything appropriately.

That being said it does seem the reporter was exposed for adding custom messages but I am uncertain of how to use this appropriately [See Pull Request 1866](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/1866)

Seems it would be something like

```
it "has a name" do |ex|
  ex.reporter.message("Custom Message Here")
  #actual test
end
```

but the html formatter seems to ignore this. I can see the output in $stdout but not in the html file itself.

Best of luck.